# What is the fastest tool or reporting option available?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, powerbi, reporting

My organization has sunset their normal reporting provider; knowledgeshare. They have replaced this with either PowerBI or SSRS reporting. My preference is for SSRS reporting however when I create dynamic reports and run them from my machine my results return in seconds while when using the service account and hitting the reporting server, the results take several minutes to return and at times never return at all.

I have been back and forth with the IT team several times with my issue - that users are not able to select their desired parameters and run the report with any kind of quick results returned but never get very far. I also sent my code to the DBA group who found no issue with the way I have written it coupled with the fact that when run from my machine or from Oracle SQL Developer everything returns well within an acceptable amount of time.

I am not a fan of nor know how to utilize PowerBI because I need to be able to use parameters since users may look up different accounts, date rangers or tax id's to retrieve the details of a report.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions or other reporting tools that I might be able to try that would allow the report to run much faster or if you've had any similar experience with PowerBI or SSRS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the main factors in selecting a reporting tool is the type of report that you are designing. SSRS is ideal for lists, tables, pivots, and printer friendly layouts. However, if you want dashboards or visualizations, it's not the best choice.

In terms of performance, there are several things you can do to tune the speed. First, you have to make sure that the server has a good connection to the data source to avoid latency. And obviously enough resources to process the report. You can also look into the caching features and balance between query parameters and report filters to optimize execution.

On a personal note, I've been working with SSRS as well as several other tools for about 7 years now and it's my favorite reporting tool.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to look into caching the reports after they've been deployed and run with the service account but they tell me with the parameters I cannot really use that. What would I look for to determine if there is a good connection to the data source? I'm fairly confident that the resources for the server are lacking but there isn't much that I can do about that - which leaves my reports not being used since they take forever to return.